# C# Array of Objects with Inheritance

Tags: c#, object, inheritance

I have a problem getting values from a child class.

```
class petstore
{
    public string name;
    public int age;

    public petstore(string name,int age)
    {
         this.name=name;
         this.age=age;
    }
}

class dog:petstore
{
    public string dogtype;

    public dog(string name, int age,string dogtype): base(name,age)
    {
        this.dogtype=dogtype;
    }
}

class cat:petstore
{
    public string cattype;

    public cat(string name, int age,string cattype): base(name,age)
    {
        this.cattype=cattype;
    }
}
```

I have that code as a class. Now I need to get the cattype or dogtype from an array of objects. 
If I did this

```
petstore[] pets=new petstore[3];
pets[0]=new dog("ben",1,"Poodle")
pets[1]=new cat("meow,2,"Persian")
```

How can I get the value of dogtype or cattype using the array pets[]?
Is it possible?
Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: That doesnt even compile.

Comment: None of this code makes any sense. The `petstore` class has a constructor named `kennel` - that won't compile. A dog is not a kind of pet store, so why does the class `dog` extend `petstore`? I think you want to rename your `petstore` class to `Pet`.

Comment: First point: *please* start following .NET naming conventions. It will make it easier to follow your example, because the subconcious won't be screaming "argh" the whole time...

Comment: Well first off you'd need to make `dogtype` and `cattype` public.  Or better yet create public properties for them instead of making fields public.  Then you'd just have to cast to the child type to get at them.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow, and to the wonderful world of development in general.  Unfortunately there are a lot of problems with this code from a stylistic perspective, so if you don't mind I'll throw in some of those thoughts along with the answer to your actual question.

**1)** Try to follow standard style conventions in whatever platform you are working on.  In the case of .NET, this means using PascalCasing when naming classes or methods.

[.NET Style Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public class PetStore {
     public void SomeMethodForTheStore() {}
}
```

**2)** When doing Object-Oriented programming, it's important to try and model your objects after the entities of your system that they represent.  In your case you have declared `Cat` and `Dog` to be subclasses of `PetStore`.  This is another way of saying that **"A dog is a type of petstore"**.  This doesn't make any sense.  As far as I know, there are no dogs that house rows and rows of cages for animals that people walk through and buy pets in.

It would be more appropriate to call your superclass `Pet`.

```
public class Dog : Pet {}
```

**3)** Finally, and I believe this is the answer to your actual question, what you are looking to do is called **casting**.  This means you are taking an object that may be housed in a more generic type and trying to move it into a more specific type so that you may take advantages of methods and properties that may only exist on that particular subclass.  In this case this is `dogtype` and `cattype`.  It also requires that you know that the instance you want to cast is of the particular type you want to cast it to.

```
// Create a polymorphic array of pets
Pet[] pets = new Pet[3];
pets[0] = new Dog("ben",1,"Poodle");
pets[1] = new Cat("meow,2,"Persian");
```

We know that the first element of the array in this case is a `Dog`, and the second is a `Cat`.  Because I know this I can cast these instances of pets to their particular type.

```
// Cast these Pets into their respective types and 
// and access their highly specialized behavior!
Dog dog = (Dog) pets[0];
Console.WriteLine(dog.DogType);

Cat cat = (Cat) pets[1];
Console.WriteLine(cat.CatType);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like we may need to take a step back and all be sure we know what you want to do.

My impression is that your project goals are to have a pet store that has different pets.

I would guess you would like to keep this simple so with that in mind; these are the things we can evaluate from the statement above like this:

A cat **is a** pet

A dog **is a** pet

A pet store **has** lots of pets - this part could get weird but we'll keep it simple for now and use the array like you showed.

Since cats and dog **are** pets - make a base class called Pet
Now make Dog and Cat classes that are children of Pet 
Now make make the PetStore an array of Pets and add your pets (dogs and/or cats).

Does that make sense?

Strictly speaking, there are better ways to do this, but this should keep it simple. :)